# WHERE clause with DropDownList selected value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this dropdownlist:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEvents" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
     AutoPostBack="True" Width="140px">
   <asp:ListItem Value="0">Choose Location</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

Above dropdownlist options are dynamically populated from the database.

Then I have this on codebehind:

```
    Public Sub BindGrid()
        Dim oconn As New SqlConnection(sqlconn)
        AddHandler ddlLocation.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ddl_SelectedIndexChanged)
        oconn.Open()
        Dim ocmd As New SqlCommand("select e.eventsId,e.Location, dbo.fnFormatDate(t.trainingDates, 'MON/DD/YYYY') t.eventDates, t.eventTime,t.eventDescription from tblEvents e, tblEventgDates t where e.eventid = t.eventid and e.eventid = " & ddlEvents.SelectedValue, oconn)
        Dim oda As New SqlDataAdapter(ocmd)
        Dim builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(oda)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        oda.Fill(ds)
        gv1.DataSource = ds
        gv1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Our users would like to filter results by selecting eventLocation from the dropdownList and have only events associated with that location to be displayed.

Code above is not doing anything.

I suspect that I need `selectedIndexChanged`?

But how do I incorporate it into the `BindData()` event?

Thanks much in advance

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class Events
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private sqlconn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ToString()
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            BindGrid()
        End If
        PopulateDates()
    End Sub
    Public Sub BindGrid()
        Dim oconn As New SqlConnection(sqlconn)
        '   AddHandler ddlEvents.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ddl_SelectedIndexChanged)
        oconn.Open()
        Dim ocmd As New SqlCommand("select e.eventsId,e.Location, dbo.fnFormatDate(t.trainingDates, 'MON/DD/YYYY') t.eventDates, t.eventTime,t.eventDescription from tblEvents e, tblEventgDates t where e.eventid = t.eventid and e.eventid = " & ddlEvents.SelectedValue, oconn)
        Dim oda As New SqlDataAdapter(ocmd)
        Dim builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(oda)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        oda.Fill(ds)
        gv1.DataSource = ds
        gv1.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub gv1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
        Dim oconn As New SqlConnection(sqlconn)
        oconn.Open()
        Dim ocmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT* FROM Events", oconn)
        Dim oda As New SqlDataAdapter(ocmd)
        Dim builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(oda)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        oda.Fill(ds)
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlInstructors"), DropDownList)
        If ddl IsNot Nothing Then
            ddl.DataSource = ds
            ddl.DataValueField = "EventsId"
            ddl.DataTextField = "EventName"
            ddl.DataBind()
        End If
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
            Dim ddldesig As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddladddesig"), DropDownList)
            ddldesig.DataSource = ds
            ddldesig.DataValueField = "EventsId"
            ddldesig.DataTextField = "EventName"

            ddldesig.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gv1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
        Dim EID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gv1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value)
        Dim oconn As New SqlConnection(sqlconn)
        oconn.Open()
        Dim ocmd As New SqlCommand()
        ocmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Events WHERE CourseID=@EID"
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", EID)
        ocmd.Connection = oconn
        ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        oconn.Close()
        BindGrid()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub gv1_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
        gv1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
        BindGrid()
    End Sub


    Protected Sub gv1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
        Dim EID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gv1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value)
        'Dim ENAME As String = DirectCast(gv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("txtename"), TextBox).Text
        Dim DESIGID As Integer = Integer.Parse(DirectCast(gv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("ddlInstructors"), DropDownList).SelectedValue)
        Dim oconn As New SqlConnection(sqlconn)
        oconn.Open()
        Dim ocmd As New SqlCommand()
        ocmd.CommandText = "UPDATE MainEvents SET EventsId=@DESIGID WHERE CourseID=@EID "
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", EID)
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESIGID", DESIGID)
        ocmd.Connection = oconn
        ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        gv1.EditIndex = -1
        BindGrid()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gv1_RowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
        gv1.EditIndex = -1
        BindGrid()
    End Sub
    Public Sub PopulateDates()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select EventsId, eventName from tblEvents order by location asc", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString))
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        ddlEvents.Items.Clear()
        Dim ddlValues As SqlDataReader
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        ddlEvents.DataSource = ddlValues
        ddlEvents.DataValueField = "EventsId"
        ddlEvents.DataTextField = "EventName"
        ddlEvents.DataBind()

        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Connection.Dispose()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdatedEventArgs)

        ' Indicate whether the update operation succeeded. 
        If e.Exception Is Nothing Then
            Dim index As Integer = gv1.EditIndex
            Dim row As GridViewRow = gv1.Rows(index)
            Message.Text = "Row updated successfully'!"
        Else
            e.ExceptionHandled = True
            Message.Text = e.Exception.Message
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem and would like to share it in case it helps someone else in the future.

Added onselectedindexchanged  to the dropdownlist

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEvents" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" Width="140px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlEvents_SelectedIndexChanged" >
   <asp:ListItem Value="0">Choose Location</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

Created the SelectedIndexChange sub and called BindGrid sub from there:

```
   Protected Sub ddlEvents_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        BindGrid()
    End Sub
```

And it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, take out the addHandler code in BindGrid(). Add parameters to BindGrid() required for selected index changed event, and wire up the event in markup:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEvents" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="BindGrid">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Choose Location</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>


    Public Sub BindGrid(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim oconn As New SqlConnection(sqlconn)        
        oconn.Open()
        Dim ocmd As New SqlCommand("select e.eventsId,e.Location, dbo.fnFormatDate(t.trainingDates, 'MON/DD/YYYY') t.eventDates, t.eventTime,t.eventDescription from tblEvents e, tblEventgDates t where e.eventid = t.eventid and e.eventid = " & ddlEvents.SelectedValue, oconn)
        Dim oda As New SqlDataAdapter(ocmd)
        Dim builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(oda)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        oda.Fill(ds)
        gv1.DataSource = ds
        gv1.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

However, I would like to propose a more simple solution. You do not need to handle SelectedIndexChanged at all in order to use it as a query parameter. Mark it up like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEvents" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Choose Location</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Markup your grid like this with a DataSourceID referring to a SqlDataSource (shown below):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="GridSqlSrc">
</asp:GridView>
```

And finally create a SqlDataSource for your grid and configure it with a parameter (prevents SQL Injection attacks) that automatically pulls from your DropDownList:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server"
SelectCommand="SELECT e.eventsId, e.Location, fnFormatDate(t.trainingDates, 'MON/DD/YYYY') t.eventDates, t.eventTime,t.eventDescription from tblEvents e, tblEventgDates t where e.eventid = t.eventid and e.eventid = @eventId)">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEvents" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="@eventId" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Now when a user selects from the DropDownList, the grid automatically re-queries and binds data.

Comment: thanks for the proposed solutions.

I like the first solution but it doesn't work.

First, I select an option from the dropdownlist, and it does not display records associated with it.

Second, when I select an option, it immediately goes back to the first option on the list.

I would have preferred this option because using the second solution would create the duplicate binding datasource error since I am already binding from codebehind.

Comment: You must have other code interfering. Can you post your entire code-behind?

Comment: sure. I have attached it above but long though.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I can see right off that you didn't add the required event handler parameters to BindGrid. In my example I show the use of 'sender' and 'e'.

Comment: I knew it had to be me!

But then, how do I pass Bindgrid to pageLoad() event and other subs that need it?

Comment: You don't actually use those parameters in this case so you could call it from other places like BindGrid(Nothing, Nothing). Or you could create another Sub that has all the code from BindGrid and have one line in BindGrid that calls it.

Comment: hmm, not the most efficient solution but if it works, I will take it for now.

I am testing and will be back with results...

Comment: It can be difficult to provide an answer that just works when the page has so many moving parts. Try stepping through with the debugger and inspect the events and data for clues to what is wrong.

Comment: there are really no moving parts. I have gone as far as commenting everything else out just to test that part only.

It just doesn't work but I am truly grateful for the efforts.